# If $f(1-x) + 2f(x) = 3x$, what is $f(0)?$

Tags: functional-equations

I did the following:

$$f(1-0) + 2f(0) = 3\cdot 0$$

$$f(1) + 2f(0) = 0$$

This reminds me of the equation of the straight line in the plane, then:

$$\left< \begin{pmatrix}
{1}\\ 
{2}
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
{f(1)}\\ 
{f(0)}
\end{pmatrix} \right> =0$$

$(1,2)$ is a normal vector to $(f(1),f(0))$, then It's possible that: $(f(1)=-2,f(0)=1)$ because:

$$\left< \begin{pmatrix}
{1}\\ 
{2}
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
{-2}\\ 
{1}
\end{pmatrix}\right> =-2+2=0$$

With generality, It is possible that for all $\alpha$:

$$\left< \begin{pmatrix}
{1}\\ 
{2}
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
{\alpha\cdot (-2)}\\ 
{\alpha \cdot 1}
\end{pmatrix}\right> = 
\left< \begin{pmatrix}
{1}\\ 
{2}
\end{pmatrix}
,
\alpha \begin{pmatrix}
{ -2}\\ 
{ 1}
\end{pmatrix}\right> =1\cdot -2\alpha+2\alpha \cdot 1=-2\alpha + 2 \alpha =0$$

I tagged with "functional equations" because it seems to be related. I don't know if my solution is correct, what I'm saying with this is that there are infinite solutions but I don't know if assuming arbitrary values for $f(1),f(0)$ can be made because of $3x$.

**EDIT:** I know that It is possible to solve: 
$$f(1) + 2f(0) = 0$$
$$f(0) + 2f(1) = 3$$

And get the solution. But why do I have to use the latter instead of the former?

Comment: What if you plugged in $x=1$ and got an expression for $f(1)$ which you could plug into the expression when $x=0$.

Comment: @Dave See the edit.

Comment: oh, hadn't seen that.

Comment: Why? Because $f(1) + 2f(0) = 0$ is just one equation with two unknowns. There are infinitely many solutions that fit this. All you have shown is that there is a particular relation between the two values $f(1)$ and $f(0)$. However there are more information in the equation you started with and taking $x=1$ gives you enough to close the equation system and get a unique solution out.

Comment: @Winther Yes. Some minutes after "solving" it, I felt that the $3x$ could "lock" the equation, but didn't know how to express it.

Answer (score 10):

Just in case if you want to solve for the actual function next time:
Substituting $x$ with $1-x$
$$f(1-(1-x))+2f(1-x)=3(1-x)$$$$f(x)+2f(1-x)=3-3x\tag{1}$$Now multiply the original equation by 2:$$2f(1-x)+4f(x)=6x\tag{2}$$
Subtract: $(2)-(1)$ We get
$$3f(x)=9x-3$$Therefore$$f(x)=3x-1$$$$f(0)=-1$$

Comment: I took the liberty to improve the equation labelling of your answer (with the command `\tag{ }`). Feel free to rollback the edit if you don't like it.

Answer (score 6):

plugging in 0, you get
$$
f(1) + 2f(0) = 0
$$
Now plug in 1 to get 
$$
f(0) + 2f(1) = 3
$$
and solve the linear system.

Comment: I am aware of this method. But why does it need to be this method?

Comment: @Voyska i tend to use the simplest mechanism available at hand. Not sure about other methods, but this would seem like it works ok

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that my method also "works".

Comment: @Voyska this proves conclusively that there is a *unique* solution to the problem (percisely because of $3x$ as you indicated) not an infinite amount...

Comment: @Voyska your method produces only one constraint for the problem. Any other solution on the same line, according to you, will work ok. But this is not true.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(1-x)+2f(x)=3x$$ 
set $1-x=t$
$$f(t)+2f(1-t)=3(1-t)$$

so $f(1-x)+2f(x)=3x$ and $f(x)+2f(1-x)=3(1-x)$
$$f(x)=3x-1$$ $f(0)=-1$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be this:

$f(1-x) + 2f(x) = 3x$

$f(1-(1-x))+2f(1-x) = 3(1-x) \implies 2f(1-x) + f(x) = 3-3x$

thus we have a system

$$\left(\begin{array}{c c}
1 & 2 \\
2  & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
f(1-x)  \\
f(x) 
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
3x  \\
3-3x 
\end{array}\right)$$
 which has unique solution $f(x) = 3x - 1$, $f(1-x) = 2-3x$, and indeed, quick check shows that this is consistent.

Comment: I've just noticed I've cross-posted with bunch of people.