# finding the value of a function for a specific input knowing the result of adding the function with different inputs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This comes from a math high school contest:

> If $$3g(x)+2g(1-x)=9+2x,$$ then what's the value of $g(2)?$

I reached the form $$g(2)=(-2g(-1)+9+2x)/3$$ but I don't know what else to try.

Comment: $$3g(2) + 2g(-1) = 13.$$  Rinse and repeat, setting $~x = -1.~$  You obtain two linear equations in the two unknowns $~g(2)~$ and $~g(-1).$

Comment: This (mutatis mutandis) answers your question: [If $f(1-x) + 2f(x) = 3x$, what is $f(0)?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820223/if-f1-x-2fx-3x-what-is-f0) + Please use a more explicit title.